# RegEx: match multi-line block by 1st and last lines

Tags: regex, plsql

There is a large block of text (a PL/SQL DDL script).

I need to remove all CREATE TABLE blocks where table name contains a dollar sign ("$"), using Python `re` library.

The PL/SQL script is relatively well formatted. In particular, the first line will always start with `CREATE TABLE` and will also contain the name of the table (i.,e. there is no line break between CREATE TABLE and the table name); the closing round bracket of the entire `CREATE TABLE ...` statement will always be the on a separate line and it will always be the only character in the line.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCH"."SOME$TABLE"
( "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
"DATA1" BLOB,
"TIMESTAMP1" DATE
)
```

I am looking for a regular expression compatible with Python's `re` library that would match the above 5 lines.

I tried the following:

```
(?m)^CREATE TABLE.*\$.*[\s\S]^\)$
```

But it is not matching anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/NnIiMR/1) what you need? I just changed `.*[\s\S]` to `[\s\S.]*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... What am I doing wrong?"*

I believe your error is with the `[\s\S]` character group, as it is only matching a single character

You could append a `+?` quantifier, to match up to the `^\)$`.

```
(?m)^CREATE TABLE.*\$.*[\s\S]+?^\)$
```